# how can i draw star triangle using recursive in prolog?

Tags: prolog

this code using to draw triangle please can any one explain how it work

```
predicates
star(integer).
count(integer,integer).
clauses
star(1):-write('*'),!.
star(X):-X<=0,!.
star(X):-count(1,X),Z=x-1,nl,star(Z),!.
count(X,Y):-X<=Y,write('*'),X1=X+1,count(X1,Y),!.
count(X<Y):-X>Y,!.
```

this code draw 5 star ,4,3,2,1
how i doing to begin from 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: with another Prolog, `?- N=5,forall(between(1,N,R),(forall(between(1,R,_),write(*)),nl)).`

Comment: Syntax errors: `<=` should be replaced by `=<` since `<=` has a different meaning in prolog. `x-1` should be `X-1`. Assignment is done with `is` not `=`, so, for example, `X1=X+1` should be `X1 is X + 1`.

Comment: @mbratch: I think that's the syntax used by Win-Prolog

Comment: @CapelliC ah ok. I'm not familiar with Win-Prolog. The OP flagged this as SWI. Which means your alternate 1-liner is a nice alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass around the upper limit:

```
star :- star(0, 5).

star(C, X) :- C < X, count(0, C), C1 is C+1, star(C1, X).
star(C, X) :- C >= X.

count(X, Y) :- X =< Y, write('*'), X1 is X+1, count(X1,Y).
count(X, Y) :- X > Y, nl.
```

Change back operators to fit your prolog (i.e. `is` become `=`, `>=` become `=>`, etc).
Note that cuts are **not** mandatory... Use with care.

```
?- star.
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: CapelliC, please can u  explain how work the count and star please

Comment: I'm a bit lazy now :) A verbose explanation is *far* more effort that writing such simple code. What's there you can't understand ?

Comment: oh,^_^ thank u very mach ... I'm  can't understand why we use star and count together

Comment: Maybe the code could be simpler, but I preferred to keep your same structure. Anyway, I think that the loop limit was **implicit** to 0 in your code, then, as I said, the necessity to pass it around...

Answer (score 3):

CapelliC gets credit for the solution, but I shall tweak it only slightly for clarity and attempt to add some explanation:

```
% Print a triangle of 1 to N stars
star(N) :- star(1, N).   % (I modified this slightly to accept N parameter)

% Print rows of NStars stars up to MaxStars stars
star(NStars , MaxStars ) :- 
    NStars =< MaxStars ,         % Print this row if NStars <= MaxStars
    row_of_stars(NStars),        % Print NStars for this row
    NStars1 is NStars+1,         % Increment the star count
    star(NStars1, MaxStars ).    % recursively print NStar1 to MaxStars triangle
star(NStars, MaxStars) :-
    NStars > MaxStars .          % Done when exceed MaxStars

% Print NumStars stars
row_of_stars(NumStars) :-
    row_of_stars(1, NumStars).   % Print NumStars starting with star number 1
row_of_stars(N, MaxStars) :-
    N =< MaxStars,               % This case is if star number doesn't exceed max
    write('*'),                  % Print a star
    N1 is N+1,                   % Increment the star count
    print_a_star(N1, MaxStars).  % Print the next star in the row
row_of_stars(N, MaxStars) :-
    N > MaxStars, nl.            % Done when exceed MaxStars
```

This problem has been broken solved using two main predicates: `star` and `row_of_stars` (formerly, `count`). The `star` predicate manages the problem at the "triangle" level. That is, it focuses on rows: how many rows to print, and how many stars each row should get when it's printed. The other predicate, `row_of_stars` (or formerly, `count`), focuses on a single, row of a given number of stars. It just prints the number of stars it's told to print. Since the problem requires recursing or iterating on rows as well as number of stars in a row, the problem is simplified by breaking the solution into these two areas.