# Make triangle of numbers in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to do some predicate in prolog. My task is to make this triangle in imsert:

```
triangle(3):-
```

this is how it should look like this:

[image: 1]

Comment: I don't see a specific question here. Please show what you've tried and ask a question regarding where you are stuck.

Comment: I just need to make some type of asterisk triangle where will be different elements, not just * 
I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913479/asterisks-triangle-in-prolog for help

Comment: You should at least show an attempt. Edit your question to add the code you already have, how you call it, what you get as output, what you expected. You can then ask a specific question about something that is still unclear to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
triangle(0).                               
triangle(N):-                              
N0 is N-1, triangle(N0), writeHalves(N). 

writeHalves(N):-                           
writeL(1, N), Ns is N-1, writeR(Ns, Ns). 

writeR(0, N):- write('\n').                
writeR(N, N):-                             
write(N), N0 is N-1, writeR(N0, N0).     

writeL(X, N):-                             
write(X), X0 is X+1, X\=N, writeL(X0, N).
writeL(N, N).
```

... although, i will leave working out the spaces up to you, as this smells 
like homework ;)
one tip: Make a triangle/2 which must be proven to call triangle/1 which takes an accumulator to count the number of spaces needed, as the other term of the predicate. i.e `triangle(N):- triangle(N, Accum)` where `Accum` equals `0` and increments.